# Dynamically change span color through CSS

Tags: css

I am working on an Angular application that has a span block in a H3 element. This span element dynamically receives a class `green` whenever it needs to turn green. I expected the following css code to work:

```
h3 span {
  background: #d2001b;
}
h3 span.green {
  background: #669900 !important;
}
```

This however always makes my span `#d2001b`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you need to turn green, the background of the span or the color of the span's text?

Comment: Ah, typo, I need to change the background color.

Comment: Can you send html that is generated? It seems either dynamic class is not added, or css selector is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a vanilla javascript example and your css appears to be correct, event without the `!important`.

Make sure that there is no other css overriding the background color.

```
span = document.querySelector('#myspan');

span.onclick = event => {
  span.classList.toggle('green');
}
```

Full example https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Ebyxwr